# Set element to display and widen using CSS transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I'm creating something simple today, but it's not behaving as I understand it should.  In essence, what I want to do is to have an element display itself, and widen from a narrow width to a wider one, when a button is clicked.

Of course there are a million ways to do this, but I'm trying to do it with a simple CSS transition.  What I have is the element set to display: none, and then adding a class which changes it to display: block and has the transition to the larger width like so:

```
<p class="cl">Click Here</p>
<div class="block"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.cl').on("click", function() {
    $('.block').addClass("widen");
  });
});

.block {
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.widen {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  transition: width 2s;
  width: 400px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cugamer/j8zuc40y/1/)

This causes the div to display, but it appears at the full, wider width when what I need it to do is appear, then take the two seconds to spread to it's full width.

As you can tell, I'm still a transitions newbie.  How should I be doing this, and what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS can't animate the change between `display: none` and `display: block`, and any other change that is bundled with them as well.

To bypass that, you need to separate the process into 2 phases:

1. display the element.
2. invoke the animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cl').on("click", function() {
    var $block = $('.block')
    $block.show();
    
    // wait for the next frame before applying the animation
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      $block.addClass("widen");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.widen {
  background-color: blue;
  transition: all 2s; /** changed transition to all to animation the color as well **/
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="cl">Click Here</p>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly.  Also, thank you for introducing me to the requestAnimationFrame function, I'd never heard of that before and I can bet I'll be getting a lot of mileage out of it.

Answer (score 1):

See if this help:
https://jsfiddle.net/j8zuc40y/4/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.cl').on("click", function() {
    $('.block').fadeIn(400);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.block').addClass('widen')
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
.block {
  background-color: red;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.widen {
  background-color: blue;
  transition: width 2s;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="cl">Click</p>

<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: This works, but Ori's requestAnimationFrame method above makes for a smoother transition.  Appreciated.